# renewcommand the chapter in chinese problem

Tags: macros, chapters

I move code from Miktex into Texlive. But I get errors:

> Run in Xelatex

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\chaptername ->第\CJKnumber 
                             {\thechapter }章
l.33 \chapter{绪论}

?
```

My minimal work is:

```
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openany]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode,xltxtra}
\usepackage[slantfont,boldfont,CJKnumber]{xeCJK}
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft} 
\usepackage[numbers,square,super,sort&compress]{natbib} 
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} 
\setromanfont{Times New Roman}
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=SimHei,ItalicFont=KaiTi]{SimSun}
\setCJKmonofont[BoldFont=SimHei]{SimSun}   
\setCJKsansfont{KaiTi}
\settowidth{\parindent}{空格} 
\setCJKfamilyfont{youyuan}{幼圆} 

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{目\hspace{1.5em}录}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{第\CJKnumber{\thechapter}章}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\bfseries\huge\filcenter}{\chaptertitlename}{1em}{}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{参考文献}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{第\CJKnumber}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{章}
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{4em}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{图}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{表}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{绪论}

\section{引言}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand from the package code, the option `CJKnumber` has been deprecated and indeed you find

```
*************************************************
* xeCJK warning: "option-deprecated"
* 
* The `CJKnumber' option is deprecated.
* You may load the package `CJKnumb' after xeCJK to use its function.
* 
*************************************************
```

in the log file. Solution:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[slantfont,boldfont]{xeCJK}
\usepackage{CJKnumb}
```

Avoid loading `xunicode` and `xltxtra`. Instructions that say to do so are outdated.

Comment: Thanks, it works. :-D
BTW, how can you know it is outdated?(xunicode and xltxtra) I'm very curious. I can learn a lot from you, I think.

Comment: @ytyyutianyun Well, loading `xunicode` has been deprecated for some years (three, IIRC). The `xltxtra` package used to be a convenient way for not remembering to load both `fontspec` and `xunicode` in the right order, but it's not needed any more as `fontspec` *does* load `xunicode` at the proper time.