# Problem polyglossia and verbatim in korean language

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, cjk, xecjk

After the question`https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550268/typewriter-font-for-korean-language/550277#550277` has been solved I'm running in the next problem, I want to have the words like `Chapter` from the `\chapter` command automatically translated.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{korean}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setCJKmainfont{Noto Sans CJK SC}
\setCJKmonofont{Noto Sans CJK SC}
%\newfontfamily\hangulfont{Noto Sans CJK SC}                                                                                        
\begin{document}

\chapter{ 다음에 의해 생성됨}
\obeylines
00027         printf({"{}JUST A PRINT STATEMENT\(\backslash\)n"{}});
00027         printf({"{}Just a print statement\(\backslash\)n"{}});
00028         printf({"large 다음에 의해 생성됨 Doxygen 1.8.19\(\backslash\)n"{}});
\begin{verbatim}
00027         printf({"{}A PRINT STATEMENT TEXT"{}});                                                                               00027         printf({"{}a print statement text"{}});                                                                               00028         printf({" 다음에 의해 생성됨 1.8.19"{}});                                                                             \end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

But this gives the error:

```
! Package polyglossia Error: The current latin font  does not contain the "Hang
ul" script!
(polyglossia)                Please define \hangulfont with \newfontfamily comm
and.

See the polyglossia package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.11 \begin{document}
```

so uncommenting the line:

```
%\newfontfamily\hangulfont{Noto Sans CJK SC}
```

but this leads to:

```
! Package polyglossia Error: The current latin font NotoSansCJKSC(1) does not c
ontain the "Hangul" script!
(polyglossia)                Please define \hangulfont with \newfontfamily comm
and.

See the polyglossia package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.18 \begin{verbatim}
```

Comment: Combining `xeCJK` and `polyglossia` is not really recommended (or at least it wasn't in 2011, see the answers to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36878/xecjk-messes-with-punctuation) because they both try to do the same thing (allow writing in different scripts) and by doing so they interfere which eachother.

Comment: The problem with the `xeCJK` is that it does not translate the `Chapter` text. So would you recommend to remove the `xeCJK / \newfont... and \setCJK` ? and replace with just `\setmainfont` and `\setmonofont`

Comment: Basically there are two choices: either use `xeCJK`, define the chapter name manually (`\renewcommand{\chaptername}` etc.) and don't use `polyglossia`, or don't use `xeCJK` and use `polyglossia` instead. From these two options `polyglossia` is a bit more feature-complete, besides the names for chapters, figures, tables etc. there are also hyphenation rules and other formatting conventions implemented that `xeCJK` doesn't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides defining

```
\newfontfamily\hangulfont{Noto Sans CJK SC}
```

it seems that it is also necessary to define:

```
\newfontfamily\hangulfonttt{Noto Sans CJK SC}
```